# How does scoping works for local variables?

Tags: bash

I was always under the impression that `local` variables were block-scoped but interestingly the following works

```
f() {
    if true; then
        local red=red
    fi

    echo "$red"
}
```

So how are `local` variables in Bash scoped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `local` variables in bash are function scoped and *not* block scoped. Also remember the `local` keyword is not applicable anywhere else beyond a function.

```
red='notred'
f() {
    if true; then
        local red=red
    fi
    echo "$red"
}
```

Now if you run the function

```
f; echo "$red"
red                # From the function's scope
notred             # From global scope
```

---

Not quite related to the actual question, but one pro-tip while using the `local` keyword, always separate the initialization with the assignment. Though it may sound trivial, if incorrectly used in a a case like this

```
f() {
    if local boolean=$(false); then
        echo 'not cool!'
    fi
}
```

and

```
f() {
    local boolean
    if boolean=$(false); then
        echo 'not cool!'
    fi
}
```

are *not* the same and the latter one is always preferred. Because `local` as such is a `bash` built-in and has a return code of its own i.e. 0 on successful assignment. On the second case, since the assignment and initialization is separated, we've ensured `local` does not sweep the failure exit code returned by the `false` command.

Answer (score 5):

[`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) says:

> Variables local to the function may be declared with the `local` builtin. These variables are visible only to the function and the commands it invokes.

Also, the section about the `local` [Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) explains:

> `local`
>
> ```
> local [option] name[=value] …
> ```
>
> For each argument, a local variable named `name` is created, and assigned `value`. The option can be any of the options accepted by `declare`. `local` can only be used within a function; it makes the variable `name` have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children.

There is no such thing as a block scope in Bash :-(

Comment: Simpler would be to use `help local`. Doesn't need so much scrolling :)

Comment: glad to hear that!

Comment: The property "visible only to the function and the commands it invokes" is used to great effect in the bash-completion library to set a variable in the calling scope, see [`upvar`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L153) - basically "namerefs before namerefs existed". http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference is an interesting resource about this.